# Apache WebServer + Tomcat + Spring + Https

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, https

I had an application running on http and then i tried to make the login page through https. Earlier apache web server used to forward request to tomcat who was a registered worker through ajp protocol. Now i added a key and certificate in `/etc/apache2/crt`, namely `ssl.key`, `ssl.crt`. There is also a `certificate.csr` file in that. The commands used for above certificate generation are from http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html I haven't done step 6 since in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` there are two files: `default` and `default-ssl`. I changed two lines in `default-ssl` :

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/crt/certificate.csr
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/crt/ssl.key
```

I also changed `server.xml` of tomcat to receive https at post 8446 :

```
<Connector port="8446" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
          clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
          keystoreFile="/etc/apache2/crt/ssl"
          keystorePass="password"/>
```

I also changed `web.xml` and it now additionally contains:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Login</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
     <!--   <url-pattern>/other/secure/stuff/*</url-pattern> -->
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I tried `curl -Iv https://localhost` and `curl -Iv https://localhost:8446` but the following error comes:

```
About to connect() to localhost port 8446 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Answer that worked partially: sudo a2ensite default-ssl and using ssl.crt Now Apache is hearing at 443 port. I want it to forward it to tomcat... trying for it..

Answer (score 2):

`SSLCertificateFile` should point to your `ssl.crt` file and not `ssl.csr` (which is only useful to submit to your Certificate Authority in order to request a certificate... after that, the CSR is not useful at all).

If you have Apache httpd performing your SSL termination (which is why you would have `SSLCertificateFile` and other directives in there), then you don't need any additional setup in Tomcat to handle `CONFIDENTIAL` communication.

If you want to configure Tomcat to accept HTTPS communication, then your `/etc/apache2/crt/ssl` file needs to be a Java Keystore, and not a bare certificate file like Apache httpd uses. Java Keystores are more complex beasts that require the use of Java's `keytool` program to manipulate.

I highly recommend that you read [Tomcat's SSL Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) which gives you step-by-step directions on how to set up your keystore correctly and configure it within Tomcat.

Comment: i had it pointed to ssl.crt initially then i thought maybe i am wrong. About the second point, i felt the same but was unsure. So should tomcat only listen to apache via ajp? thanks for the answer, let me try ur suggestions.. btw i wanted apache to do all stuff and let tomcat be unaware of https..

Comment: i made it pointed to ssl.crt. Removed content from web.xml Still no help. On browser i get:  err 102 - "The server refused the connection."

Comment: Only you can decide what makes sense for your own environment: you can choose to use Apache httpd as a fronting web server or not. Tomcat is a perfectly good web server and, when configured properly, competes well performance-wise with Apache httpd. If configuring Apache httpd is easier for you to configure SSL (and you get some other benefits from it) then feel free to have Apache httpd to the SSL termination for you and only use AJP to connect the two. If you don't need Apache httpd for anything else, it might be worth your while to eliminate it from your setup and only use Tomcat.

Comment: Shut down Tomcat and delete all the log files. Then, start Tomcat and look at `logs/catalina.out` and any other log files that are created: there should be some kind of error messages in there if Tomcat won't start properly.